# searching a 2D array given the address of one element

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments, argument-passing

A rather quick question concerning pointers in c++

My problem is,let's say I have a function isWon(char * sign, int i, int j). I call this method by giving

- the address of an element in a 2D array
- it's coordinates in a locally declared array

Is there any way of e.g. knowing the elements neighbors and getting to them?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: given the constraints of your parameters, there isn't even a way to know what i and j *mean*. You know `i` is in  0...N, and a `j` is in 0...M, but without at least knowing M in addition `i` and `j`, you have no context of the row-major extremum and thus no way of using that point in a defined manner. Knowing *neighbors* means knowing where `table[i][j]` is *first*, which in your case is `sign[i*M+j]`. Knowing `M` is mandatory or this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is a true array 2D array and not an array of pointers or something like that, then you can add/subtract to/from `sign` to get other elements' addresses.

For example, **memory-wise** the previous element in the array is at `sign - 1`. If you think of your 2D array as a grid, `sign - 1` might not be the element in the previous "column".

---

You have to be careful how much you step in your array and ask yourself why you resort to such low-level dangerous mechanisms that feel out of place in C++.

Comment: actually, when I type (sign -1) in the input I get the whole string starting from the sign-1 sign. Also, after I type (char) before, an interpretation of ascii code gets out.